# How to get Facebook share button?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I was able to share content from my iOS application to Facebook using this code:

```
    @IBAction func fbAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
        let fbShare:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        let url = URL(string: picturebookstring)
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
        fbShare.setInitialText(titlebookstring + " book is available now on our application")
        fbShare.add(UIImage(data: data!))
        fbShare.add(URL(string: "http://bookmooch.com/"))


        self.present(fbShare, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to your Facebook account ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}
```

I do it after clicking a simple button, now I want to change this button with Facebook share button.

Can I get this button without passing through the Facebook iOS SDK? 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios

Comment: Do you want to change the appearance of your button ?

Comment: yes ! something like this : http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/IMG_0471-169x300.jpg but without using the facebook sdk

Comment: I am not able to open the link which you shared, does it something like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/br4Br.png

Comment: Yes exactly like this

Comment: Then you can change the button image from the storyboard.

Comment: thank's a lot , I was thinking that I must pass through facebook (sdk-developper account) if you have another picture for twitter share kindly post it

Comment: Search it on google, you can get a lots of images :)